# Connect to .xlsx sheet from c# -office2016 installed: External table is not in the expected format

Tags: excel, connection, oledb, xlsx, office-2016

### Problem

I HAVE OFFICE 2016 INSTALLED ON MY MACHINE and I am trying to open connection to .xlsx sheet but getting an error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in Tester.exe

Additional information: External table is not in the expected format.

### Additional info

Note that connection opens for .xls files

I HAVE OleDbConnectionString METHOD RETURNING

```
String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                                               "Data Source=" + path + ";" +
                                               "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;\""
                );
```

I PROVIDE THE FULL SHEET PATH

```
var path = @"C:\Users\a\Desktop\b\b\Tester\Excel\demo.xlsx";
```

---

I USE THE METHOD IN

```
 var excelConnectionString = Data.OleDbConnectionString(sheetPath);
            oleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
            oleDbConnection.Open();
```

---

I am not using ace.oledb cause it rendered another error!

Comment: ah okkk!  But when I set Excel 12.0 in the connection string I get the error: Could not find installable ISAM.

Comment: And when I set Excel 12.0 with Ace.OleDb (and not jet.oledb) I get  "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Comment: Thank you! I should have checked this before! But I thought it comes with MS Office and I got lost!

Comment: I looked in the registry -- Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0 but did not find the  Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable, I downloaded and installed it but I still get: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Comment: I solved the problem but the solution is weird. When I installed Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable it did not work. When I installed also M ACE 2007 with the 2010 v it worked! M ACE 2016 installation did not help me.But  If I remove 2007 version, I get that the provider is not found. pb solved and with both M Ace 2007 and 2010 the provider is found!